# Is it possible to select nth-child(x) but only if it is not the last child?

Tags: css

I want to select the third element within a `ul`, only if it is not the last element in the `ul`.

Sample 1:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Cat 1</li>
  <li>Subcat 1</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>
```

Sample 2:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Cat 1</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>
```

I want a single CSS selector, which, for sample 1, selects the `li` with "Subcat 1", and for sample 2, does not select anything.

`ul > li:nth-child(3)` will work for sample 1, but will also match the 'Product' li in sample 2, which I don't want it to do.

In this case I'm not able to modify the HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the :nth-child with :not to achieve what you need. here is an example.

```css
ul li:nth-child(3):not(:last-child) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sample1">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Cat 1</li>
  <li>Subcat 1</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>


<ul class="sample2">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Cat 1</li>
  <li>Product</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic CSS approach here, without using `:not` (which can sometimes be tricky), is to give the general rule first, then override it with the special case.

```
ul > li:nth-child(3) { color: red; }
ul > li:last-child   { color: inherit; }
```

> I want a single CSS selector,

If this is important, you'll need to use `:not`.

Comment: Just being pedantic, you can avoid using not with nth-last-child(n+1)   ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:last-child` selector. So it would be something like this:

```
ul >li:last-child {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

[More about :last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_last-child.asp)

Comment: But he wants to select the second child, if it is **not** the last child.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul > li:nth-child(3):not(:last-child), ul > li:nth-child(2):not(:last-child) {
    color: red;
}
```